# how can i change the visibility of a menu item inside onOptionsItemSelected(..)

Tags: android, menuitem, android-optionsmenu

i have three menu items "enable, diable, exit". what i want to do is, when the R.id.menu_enable_bt is chosen, i want to disable it using

```
menu.findItem(R.id.menu_enable_bt).setVisible(false);
```

but i can not call

```
menu.findItem(R.id.menu_enable_bt).setVisible(false);
```

from inside the onOptionsItemSelected(..) method.

how can i change the visibility of a menu item inside onOptionsItemSelected(..)

**CODE**:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    Log.w(TAG, SubTag.msg("onCreateOptionsMenu"));

    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);

    if (this.mBTAdapter.isEnabled()) {
        menu.findItem(R.id.menu_enable_bt).setVisible(false);
        menu.findItem(R.id.menu_disable_bt).setVisible(true);
    } else {
        menu.findItem(R.id.menu_enable_bt).setVisible(true);
        menu.findItem(R.id.menu_disable_bt).setVisible(false);
    }

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    Log.w(TAG, SubTag.msg("onOptionsItemSelected"));

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menu_enable_bt:
            Log.d(TAG, SubTag.bullet("onOptionsItemSelected", "menu_enable_bt"));

            //menu.findItem(R.id.menu_enable_bt).setVisible(false);  **how to do this**
            this.mATEnableBT = new ATEnableBT();
            this.mATEnableBT.execute();
            break;

        case R.id.menu_disable_bt:
            Log.d(TAG, SubTag.bullet("onOptionsItemSelected", "menu_disable_bt"));

            break;

        case R.id.menu_exit:
            Log.d(TAG,SubTag.bullet("onOptionsItemSelected", "menu_exit"));

            finish();
            break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use [invalidateOptionsMenu()](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/app/Activity.html#invalidateOptionsMenu()) which will forse `onCreateOptionsMenu` to be called again.

From the documentation

> Declare that the options menu has changed, so should be recreated. The
>   onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu) method will be called the next time it needs
>   to be displayed.

There you can check your conditions and undertake the needed actions

Answer (score 0):

See the javadoc for [onPrepareOptionsMenu](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onPrepareOptionsMenu%28android.view.Menu%29).  This is your opportunity to make changes to a menu just before it becomes visible to the user.  So you should maintain some member variables describing what should be visible and use that to modify the menu items here.

Comment: but i think i still do the same job with onCreateOptionsMenu() and i have to use some variables describe what should be visible...but wha i need is something like diabling the item to make no, for an example, not clickable once touched

Comment: If you read the javadoc for the method I linked, it specifically says it's used for the cause you're mentioning.  onCreateOptionsMenu is used to create the menu ONCE, and then it's reused from that point on. After it's created once, you simply modify it after that.  This is standard practice.